# Sublime Text 3 build system with Elm

Tags: sublimetext3, elm

I tried to find a way to make a build system on sublime which builds and opens the generated html file in a browser without any luck.
I added to the .sublime-build for Elm Make an additional variant which should open the generated file in chrome:

```
{
        "name": "Run and Show",
        "shell": true,
        "cmd":
        [
            "elm-make",
            "$file",
            "--output={output}",
            "--report=json",
            "--yes",
            "&&",
            "google-chrome",
            "--new-window",
            "{output}"
        ]
    },
```

This prints the following command in sublime's console:

```
Running elm-make Test.elm --output=build/index.html --report=json --yes && google-chrome --new-window {output}
```

So it seems that elm-make is running and generating the build/index.html file and then it should not open the chrome window (as {output} won't get replaced), but actually nothing happens.
Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Which OS are you on? Do you have `google-chrome` CLI available? In other words, does the same command do what you expect it to do if you run it straight from the shell?

Comment: Yes, it works in console. I'm on kubuntu 14.04.